# is it possible to connect to server created on react native applicattion?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have created a server using  react-native-static-server on my RN applicaion.I want to connect to this server using sockets and have tried socket.io,react native tcp socket is there any way to do ?my server app and my client app are on same phone. I want both these apps to talk to each other

my static server app

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';

import StaticServer from 'react-native-static-server';

import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

let path = RNFS.ExternalDirectoryPath + '/www';

const io = require('socket.io')();

import {Text} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    io.on('connection', client => {
      let server = new StaticServer(8000, path, {localOnly: true});
      server.start().then(url => {
        console.log('Serving at URL', url);
      });
    });
    io.listen(8000);
  });

  return <Text>hello</Text>;
}
```